# Swift Firebase UIActivityViewController Share Image

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, uiactivityviewcontroller

Need some help on sharing an image downloaded from Firebase using the UIActivityViewController. My current setup only presents the "More" option when the UIActivityViewController is presented. Nothing else is presented for share options.

```
let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        var items:[Any] = []

        let titlePost = self.feeds[sender.tag].downloadURL

        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: titlePost)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {(data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("image could not be downloaded")
            } else {
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        self.image = img
                        items.append(img)
                        print("image downloaded")
                    }
                }
            }
        })


        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
```

Comment: `getData` runs asynchronously, the code after the closure is getting called before the work inside of it is completed. You need to incorporate a way to wait until the work is done before showing the `UIActivityViewController`. [This article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f) gives a few suggestions for handling async code in Swift.

Comment: Thanks, yet I realized I just had to move my "activityViewController" call inside the firebase storage reference parameters "})". That's what made it work.